# Allow SFTP and process running but disallow ssh for a single user

Tags: ssh, sftp

as the title said, i want to disallow ssh access for a user, but allow the user to execute a java process and access SFTP

How this can be done?

Comment: Have you thought about FTPS? http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/75602/Understanding-Key-Differences-Between-FTP-FTPS-and-SFTP

Comment: You probably need two users to achieve this securely and easily. One user with the sftp access Henrique describes, A second with a authorized_key file that will run the the specific `command=""` on login in the link of Roberts

Answer (score 2):

You can create a group called sftponly.

Add the user to this group and configure ssh

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Added Conf:

```
Match Group sftponly
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Now the users in this group will only be able to sftp

There is a smal problem with this setup, is that chroot from ssh it needs that the %h (home variable) be owned by root. With this variablke you can do this for multiple users.

so it would be like this:

```
/home/user1   ( root owner )
/home/user1/public_html ( user1 owner )
```

Does not need to be public_html it can be any folder name... example Java

Comment: OP needs to execute a command as well. This config won't allow that for `user1`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easy way to disallow ssh access for most things is to change their shell environment variable in their profile.  Check here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-disable-shell-ftp-access-to-newuser/

If you want them to be able to access highly specific commands, check http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/jpmg/ssh/authorized_keys_howto.html - you'll need to give them an authorized key (rather than a password), and follow the instructions in the "Forced command" section so that it'll always run the exact same command when they log in, ignoring whatever they send to it.

Comment: I know how to edit the shell to nologin, but I need shell access to execute the Java process, as i stated in the question. A process can be executed without a shell?